# Save and Load Objects Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Following is the code.

**To Store an Object into a shared preference**

```
public void saveObject()
    {
        AccountVO accountVO1 = new AccountVO("1", "scott", "password", "scott@mail.com", "Scott", "Stanford");

        accountsSharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences("AccountsPrefsFile",Context.MODE_WORLD_PRIVATE);
        accountsPreferenceEdit = accountsSharedPreference.edit();

        accountsPreferenceEdit.putString("accountObject", accountVO1.toString());
        accountsPreferenceEdit.commit();
}
```

**To retrieve the object from the same shared preference**

```
public AccountVO loadObject()
    {
        AccountVO accountVO1 = null;

        accountsSharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences("AccountsPrefsFile",context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String accounntsObjectString = accountsSharedPreference.getString("accountObject", "");

        //My issue ? --- How to retreive the AccountVO object from "accountObject" String here????

        return accountVO1;
}
```

My AccountVO class code is as follows:

```
    public class AccountVO
    {

        private String id;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private String email;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

public AccountVO(String tempID, String tempUserName, String tempPassword, String tempEmail, String tempFirstName, String tempLastName)
    {
            this.id = tempID;
            this.username = tempUserName;
            this.password = tempPassword;
            this.email = tempEmail;
            this.firstName = tempFirstName;
            this.lastName = tempLastName;   
        }
        public String getId()
        {
            return id;
        }
        public String getUserName()
        {
            return username;
        }
        public String getEmail()
        {
            return email;
        }
        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName;
        }
    }
```

**Anyone tell me how to retrieve AccountVO object from accountObject string in the loadObject method.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't construct an Object using the `toString()` property. `Object.toString()` only returns the hash value representation of the object, not a memory address or anything else. This means multiple objects can return the same result from `toString()`. Eg:
`new Byte(10).toString()` and `"10".toString()`

To store your object in the SharedPreferences, I'd suggest you store them as key value pairs given that you know the exact format of a AccountVO object. (Add a helper in that class probably to return a key-value pair map for you)

**OR**

Override the toString method in you AccountVO class to return a String that you can easily decipher later when retrieved later from the SharedPreferences. Like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return id+"<delim>"+username+"<delim>"+password+"<delim>"+email+"<delim>"+firstName+"<delim>"+lastName;
}
```

Then in your `loadObject()` method, reconstruct the Object using:

```
public AccountVO loadObject()
{
    AccountVO accountVO1 = null;

    accountsSharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences("AccountsPrefsFile",context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String accounntsObjectString = accountsSharedPreference.getString("accountObject", "");

    String[] parts = accounntsObjectString.split("<delim>");

    return new accountVO1(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
}
```

Comment: That or just make it Parcelable

Comment: I'm assuming the OP wants to store the whole object between App runs, not just between Activities.

Comment: Yeah, didn't realize that. Parcelable not good for that. Derp

Comment: @varevarao Thanks for all the inputs

Answer (score 2):

Here is a far more clear and simple way to save objects to `SharedPreferences`.  Google's GSON is awesome.

Convert your object to a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) string using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) then save it to `SharedPreferences`:

```
AccountVO accountVO1 = new AccountVO("1", "scott", "password", "scott@mail.com", "Scott", "Stanford");

accountsSharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences("AccountsPrefsFile",Context.MODE_WORLD_PRIVATE);
accountsPreferenceEdit = accountsSharedPreference.edit();

Gson gson = new Gson();
String objStr = gson.toJson(accountV01);

accountsPreferenceEdit.putString("accountObject", objStr);
accountsPreferenceEdit.commit();
```

To retrieve your saved object, do this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
accountsSharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences("AccountsPrefsFile",Context.MODE_WORLD_PRIVATE);
String savedObjStr = accountsSharedPreference.getString("accountObject", null);
if(savedObjStr != null) {
    AccountVO accountVO1 = gson.fromJson(savedObjStr, AccountVO.class);
}
```